# Is there a Linux function to check if a filename with differing case exists?

Tags: c++, linux, file, case-sensitive

**Is there a Linux function to check if a filename with differing case exists?** e.g. to find the difference between Hello.txt and hello.txt

For example if I wanted to open Hello.txt I would like to do:

- try to open a file ( try *Hello.txt*)

if that fails:

- check if there is a file with different case in the folder (find file *hello.txt*)

Comment: You can get a list of all the files in the directory, convert all to lower case and compare against the filename you are looking for, also lower-cased.

Comment: Not an answer for your question, but potentially helping you solving your problem: For some linux file systems (like ext4) you can enable case-insensitivness for specific folders.

Comment: *check if there is a file with different case in the folder (find file hello.txt)* -- I will be honest with you -- this is too much hand-holding to the user.  Just present the message that the file "Hello.txt" does not exist, and let the user (who I would believe is competent) figure out that the file they have is actually "hello.txt".  If the user is a Linux/Unix user, then they are well aware of  file names and case-sensitivity issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If such function were to exist, there will be 2<sup>n</sup> combinations to check where `n` is the length of the file name.

For `hello.txt`, if you include the extension, there will be 256 ways to check (2<sup>8</sup> = 256). As with exponential time complexity, it becomes an unmanageable problem very fast as n grows.

This is hugely inefficient and so the best way to do case-insensitive filename match is to convert everything to lower (or upper) case and then compare them like @mark-setchell points out.

Since you tagged c++ and linux, I have included a solution which works on linux, written in c++. Remember the function `strcasecmp` is only present on linux systems.

Also, if we keep track of the index of the match, we need not go through the 2<sup>n</sup> iterations if we need the exact case sensitive file name.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
  std::string path = "./";
  std::string to_find = "hello.txt";
  bool exists = false;
  int found_index = 0;
  std::vector<std::string> arr;
  for (const auto &entry: std::filesystem::directory_iterator(path)) {
    arr.push_back(entry.path());
  }
  std::sort(arr.begin(), arr.end()); //std::filesytem::directory_iterator's 
                                //order cannot be determined, so the
                                //vector is sorted. This step is optional though
  for (int i=0; i<arr.size(); i++) {
    std::string a = arr[i].substr(path.size()); // Remove prefix path
    if (strcasecmp(a.c_str(), to_find.c_str()) == 0) {
      exists = true;
      found_index = i;
      break;
    }
  } 
  if (exists) {
    std::cout << "File found and the exact file name is \"" << arr[found_index] << "\"" << std::endl;
  } else {
    std::cout << "File not found" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

If match is found the above program prints out the exact file name too.

Answer (score 3):

No, there isn't. You'll need to iterate the files in the directory and do the check manually. There are functions to help with that though, e.g. [`scandir`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scandir.3.html). Since C++17 you have [`std::filesystem::directory_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator) to iterate through the directory and generic algorithms in the standard library to help with the implementation if needed.

Also, some file systems are case-insensitive and will consider these two equivalent file names anyway. But in general Linux considers file names as just a sequence of byte values. So you will also need to decide in what encoding you want to interpret the file name if there are non-ASCII value in there. If you assume a Unicode encoding, figuring out what exactly "differing case" means is also not trivial.